# T-SQL capturing Linked server name as a result column

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql, oracle11g

How can I capture the (linked) server (in this case Morpheus) name as a column of the result. I do not want to define the Server name in the query itself.

```
exec("
    select 
                COMNO
                ,T$CPLS ""Catalog"" 
                ,T$CUNO ""Customer ID.""
                ,T$CPGS ""Price Group""
                ,T$ITEM ""Item Code""
                ,T$UPCD UPC
                ,T$DSCA ""Description""
                ,T$WGHT ""Weight""
                ,T$SHIP ""Shipping Indicator""
                ,nvl(T$STDT,to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')) ""From""
                ,nvl(case T$TDAT
                            when '4712-01-01' then ' ' 
                            when null then '  '
                            else t$tdat 
                         end,'  ')  ""To"" 
                ,nvl(t$qanp,99999999) ""Qty.""
                ,T$PRIC ""List Price""
                ,T$DISC ""Discount""
                ,to_char(round(t$pric * (1-t$disc/100),2),99999.99) ""Net""
                ,Source ""Source"" 
            from Table(edi.ftCompositCatalog(?,?,?)) --where trim(t$item)='105188-041'
      order by Source,t$cpgs,t$item",'010','145','000164') at morpheus
```

Comment: you have tags "tsql" and "oracle11g". It's either one or the other - T-SQL is SQL Server, whereas Oracle 11g uses PL/SQL. You may want to fix your tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, when running your query, you already know what linked server you are pointing to, then just include that as a string literal in your result:

```
exec("
    select
     'morpheus' ""Server Name""
    ,T$CPLS ""CATALOG""
...
```

Even if the linked server name is being stored in a variable, you can do this easily since you're building your query string dynamically.

If, as you say, you don't want to define it as a string literal, here is a normal way to get the host (server) name in Oracle:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST') FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to embed this as a subquery or inline view in your query, I think it would work.

*Please note that some organizations & dba's do not *want* you to know anything about the backend environment for security reasons, but assuming you have no roadblock there, this should work.

Comment: Ghost,Apologise I did not mention that I do not want servername to be explicitly specified in the query. Edited the question to reflect the requirment.